# Does the return statement of the function which the thread executes automatically kill the thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

After `function2` executes and is returned, would the thread be killed automatically and do I need to `join()` the thread or do something to make sure that it is completely gone in function1?

```py
def function1():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    Thread(target=function2, args=(a,b,)).start()
```

```py
def function2(a, b):
    print(a + b) 
    return()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The thread will terminate on its own. The `join()` function is a convenience that tells the *parent* thread to block until the child thread is finished (so if the child thread hasn't finished yet, then the parent thread won't continue).

You can see evidence of this on the python console (even before I call `t.join()`, the thread is already dead):

```
>>> def function1():
...     print("Hello!")
...     return 5
... 
>>> t = threading.Thread(target=function1)
>>> t.start()
Hello!
>>> t.is_alive()
False
>>> t.join()
>>> t.is_alive()
False
```